# ionic list with filter search and limitTo, safari crash

Tags: search, safari, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll, angular-filters

I've an ionic app with a large list of data.
To show it I've added the infinite scroll and a search filter: you can see a similar app here: http://embed.plnkr.co/ikUeQS37R5wUXHY76KPE/
All works fine in chrome, but if I execute this code in Safari, the search bar donot works, and when execute the same code in app on ios, the app crash!!

Help me please...